# Is it possible to use cpu.shares with cpu.cfs_quota_us

Tags: cgroups

I'm setting up cgroups config for my research team. The server has 8 cpus. The team member could only use part of the cpu time, so for the team I set `cpu.cfs_quota_us = 400000`. I also want to add task priority with cpu.shares.

for example, here's my cgroup config:

```
group team {
    cpu {
        cpu.cfs_period_us = 100000;
        cpu.cfs_quota_us = 400000; #4 CPUs
    }
}

group team/user1 {
    cpu {
        cpu.shares = 256;
    }
}

group team/user2 {
    cpu {
        cpu.shares = 768;
    }
}
```

the cpu.shares only work if I set the parent group's cpu.cfs_quota_us to -1 and all cpu are in use.

Could cpu.cfs_quota_us and children's cpu.shares work together?

Answer (score 0):

`cpu.shares` is not made to set task priority.

It's used to define a relative (abstract) amount of CPU sharing, meaning, when a CPU is dedicated to tasks of a certain group/user instead of another.

Here you basically say that `team/user2` will have three times (768/256) more dedicated computation time than `team/user1` for his tasks. In other words, `team/user2` will use 75% of CPU time and `team/user1` only 25%.

`cpu.shares` and `cpu.cfs_quota_us` do the same thing but in two different manners.
The former is using relative representation of time sharing and the later is using exact quantification in microseconds. Because they are both used to define CPU time sharing, they cannot be used together.

Some docs: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/sec-cpu

Comment: thanks, any suggestion if I want to set relative cpu time sharing inside a cgroup?
install a virtual machine will work, but it is to heavy.

Comment: You first wanted to know how to set **priorities** on tasks, which is not possible, you only can set cpu time sharing (in two different ways).
Your answer is right to set cpu time sharing per group. You set that group `team/user1` will have less CPU time than `team/user2`. See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/sec-cpu_and_memory-use_case

Comment: @A.Gille can you provide more specific evidence on why they "cannot be used together"? I reviewed the link you provided but could not corroborate that. Also, this SO answer seems to interpret it differently: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55914709/3865626

Comment: @oxley Read the docs first. In **3.2.1. CFS Tunable Parameters**: "The following options can be used to configure ceiling enforcement **OR** relative sharing of CPU". As I said, they are two different ways/manners/approaches to achieve the same goal. Try it yourself. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/sec-cpu