# What is the relationship between cpu.shares and cpu.cfs_quota_us in context of cgroup?

Tags: cpu, cgroups, cfs

I'm using centos6/7 and using cgroup to manage cpu resources. I have read through the [RHEL document](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide) but have no answer to my question below:

If I set both cfs_quota_us and shares among cgroups, then what will happen?

(e.g. will cfs_quota_us take precedence over shares?)

Thank you in anticipation!

Answer (score 6):

My understanding is that for the same level of two cgroups (only), e.g.:

```
foo
 |
 +- bar
 |
 +- baz
```

Then *bar* and *baz* will firstly share the cpu occupied on *foo* according to `cpu.share`.

Let's say the overall cpu is 1 core with `cpu.cfs_period_us` set as **100ms**. `cpu.share` is set as **1024** for *bar* and **1024** for *baz*.

1. if both *bar* and *baz* are setting `cpu.cfs_quota_us` more than **50ms**, for example, **75ms**. Then both cgroup will share the cpu by half, with exact value of **50ms**.
2. if both of them has `cpu.cfs_quota_us` set less than **50ms**, for example, **25ms**. They will still share cpu 1:1, but with the exact value of **25ms**.
3. what if *bar* is setting quota as **25ms**, while *baz* setting quota as **75ms** (this is exactly what I wondered).  Since *bar* and *baz* has the same `cpu.share`, and *bar* has upper limit set as **25ms**, this means *bar* should never exceeds **25ms**. So given a 100ms period, *bar* will consume **25ms**. **Will *baz* also consume 25ms as *bar* because of same `cpu.share`? If yes, then how do we put the 50ms left?**

   According to RHEL6's [document](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/sec-cpu#sect-cfs):

   > Because the CFS does not demand equal usage of CPU, it is hard to predict how much CPU time a cgroup will be allowed to utilize. When tasks in one cgroup are idle and are not using any CPU time, the leftover time is collected in a global pool of unused CPU cycles. Other cgroups are allowed to borrow CPU cycles from this pool.

   We can see that it is legal for *baz* to consume the unsed CPU cycles, i.e. *baz* will consume **75ms** in one period.

**Conclusion**

`cpu.share` and `cpu.cfs_quota_us` are working together.

Given a total cpu quota, we should firstly distribute the `cpu.share` of each cgroup. Then find the cgroups whose exact quota exceeds their `cpu.cfs_quota_us`, find all such cgroups and keep their quota as their `cpu.cfs_quota_us`, and collect the exceeded part as unused cpu pool. Distribute these unused cpu pool among other cgroups by `cpu.share` again, and iterate as above, until no cgroup is exceeding the upper limit.